# LTspice XVII Error Handling

Tags: ltspice

I got a model from net and want to open it, but I encounter with this error. Can somebody there help?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you might show us the model you got?

Comment: That's not a model, it's a footprint info file, used for routing & co. If you're looking for an `.asc` file, that's not the same as ASCII.

Comment: "A model" need more info.